# Android : Google sign in api returning Null

Tags: android, device, sign

I followed up tutorial on how to use google sign in in app and it is working fine in Emulator.

When I created an signed apk with release type and send to my sister via email to check if she is able to login, after selecting her user account for login she is not able to login. The Google api returns null during the login process.

```
 private void showSignedInUI()
{
    // TODO: Start making API requests.
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String emailuser = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + emailuser
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);


            CollectDetails cd = CollectDetails.getInstance();
            cd.setUserName(personName);
            cd.setemailAddress(emailuser);

            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;
            cd.setPhotoURL(personPhotoUrl);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(GooglePlayServicesActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: if you don't show what exactly you do, and what exactly happens, people can not help you. so give your code and any logs that make sense.

Comment: have you generated the signed key. You might have used debug key for developing. You would require sha1

Comment: Hi Raghunandan, This is how is registered my app, I went to this site  https://console.developers.google.com/ clicked on API , clicked on credentials-> Installed application -->  Choose Android--->Entered my package name and the Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) which i created from the terminal, Chose google+ deep linking. Prior to this i created certificate using command keyhole -exportcert -alias android debugkey -keystore ~ /.android/debug.keystore -list -v

Comment: Finally figured out as you said Raghunandagn it was the SH1 key error which was preventing the Google API from returning data.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks sir ...... i m also facing this problem and your advice short out my problem. thanks again sir...